# Is Migrate module supposed to be used for imports too?

Tags: entities, importing-exporting, 8

I am in need of an entity import functionality so I started to write my own. But then I started to think if I'm not reinventing the wheel and it occurred to me that maybe Migrate module will be used for this(beside it's main purpose)?

I mean, since all entity fields are objects with their own specifications regarding data they work with, Migrate will probably handle all of this. So am I correct to assume this or should I continue to work on my module? Because right now I started to think about the field objects(FieldDefinition for core fields and FieldInstanceConfig for field API fields) and I would need to write a lot of data handlers for each type of field and data-type it's working with(boolean, text, file/image, float,...) which will be a lot of work.

On the other hand Migrate would probably have all this data-handlers already in place so they could be reused?

---

By entity import I mean creating data from csv, xls, xml... files.

Comment: Are you working on Drupal 8? If yes, Migrate module has no package for 8.

Comment: Yes D8, that's why this is tagged by '8', though I know it can easily be overlooked. And by import I mean creating entities from files like csv, excel and such. I've edited the original post to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! That's why we split migrate_drupal and migrate. The latter is the API, it has the destinations, like the entities you are asking for. Handbook page is at https://drupal.org/node/2127611 useful article at http://webikon.com/cases/migrating-to-drupal-8

Comment: So in order to present my custom entity import UI to the user with option to select which columns he want's to import from lets say CSV file and to which entity fields to map them I would have to write some sort of UI module that would export such settings into a migrate configuration file and only after that run it?

Comment: Yes please. We are much interested in such a UI; it's somewhat planned for contrib.

Comment: Is there sandbox project for this?

Comment: The IMP sandbox focuses on core parts. We do not yet have ventured into contrib; core has priority.

Answer (score -2):

Also [github.com/larowlan/default_content](https://github.com/larowlan/default_content) for module provided entities